# Safari Extension Message passing form web page to background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-extension

I want to execute message passing between webpage and safari background (global) script. I am actually looking for a function similar to `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener` of chrome extension. I was not able to find such functionality in safari extension methods.

So is there a way to communicate with extension background or content script in asynchronous way for message passing?